# Bulk insert not working for NULL data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, csv, bulkinsert

When I am inserting bulk data to a table from a CSV file, it is not working, showing error lie :

Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 9

Column 9 value in csv file is null..

How do I take care of this?

Comment: Provide your sample data and temporary table schema using in bulk insert than only it can trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this amount of information I'd say the target table's particular field is defined as "NOT NULL". To workaround the issue you have to:
**a)** modify csv-->add value to field(s) where they have null
**b)** modify target table by setting affected fields 'nullable':`ALTER TABLE [tblName] ALTER COLUMN [nulColName] [varType such as INT] NULL`
In case you go for this solution and want to turn back table's status alter it again:
`UPDATE [tblName] SET [nulColName]=-1000 WHERE [nulColName] IS NULL` to avoid alter errors, then `ALTER TABLE [tblName] ALTER COLUMN [nulColName] [varType such as INT] NOT NULL`
**c)** pretty much like 'b' option but a bit more professional and faster: create a temp table based on target table but allowing nulls to any and all fields, then update temp table's null records after csv import with a "default value" and copy the data to the target table
*If I'm right about the issue and there's no option to revise csv I'd go for option 'c'*

Comment: Without seeing the table script, I think B is a great place to start.